# Using one Django model to make multiple tables which are exact copies of that model but with different names?

Tags: python, django, model

Heres my scenario:

I have a form that a user fills out.
At the end of the session, all of the form data is displayed to the user.
Simultaneously a reference form is rendered next to the user's form and shows recommended or  default values.

So the schema I believe I need for this would be a MySQL table layout similar to:

```
DATABASE
   |___FormTable-User
   |      |_var1
   |      |_var2
   |      |_var3
   |
   |___FormTable-Refrence
          |_var1
          |_var2
          |_var3
```

Is there a way to configure models.py to make copies of model classes, or create a model that inherit the fields of another?

theory:

```
class userForm(models.Model):
    var1 = models.IntegerField()
    var2 = models.IntegerField()
    var3 = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "FormTable-User"

class refrenceForm(userForm):
    #inherits all fields from userForm so -
    #makemigrations detects this as its own model 
    #but will always be an exact copy of userForm.
    #only difference is the table name...
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "FormTable-Refrence"
```

And thank you all for your kind wisdom!